# Socket closed when connecting windows service bus using amqp from Java

Tags: java, amqp, windows-server, servicebus

I am trying to connect to service bus for windows server using the [Java example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn574799.aspx) which is provided on Microsoft website.

Below are the libraries I am using for this POC

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.26.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms</artifactId>
        <version>0.32</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the connection string format I am using

```
  return "amqps://" + SbSharedKey + ":" + SbSharedSecret + "@" + SbDomain + "/" + SbNamespace;
```

I have the exact same code as is there on the website, but is giving below error

> Initial setup Creating context Creating connection factory Creating
> connection
>
> Creating session
> Exception creating session/producer
>
> java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed   at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
> javax.jms.JMSException: class java.net.SocketException: Connection
> closed by remote hostclass java.net.SocketException: Connection closed
> by remote host    at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)   at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)   at
> sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)  at
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

I tried to do [SSLPoke](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-779355358.html) and it is giving a success,

So issue is only with AMQP side it seems.

Can you please point me to the correct version of libraries to use when connecting to a Windows server service bus using amqp from Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using below versions of jar's

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms</artifactId>
        <version>0.22</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different AMQP JMS client library dependencies on your project so I've no idea what's really going on, but my first guess is that you end up using the legacy 'qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms' client which is not supported and definitely not going to work.  I'd remove that and try to get things going with just the Qpid JMS 0.26.0 client library, although I believe there's some other URI options you might need as azure has some specific requirements in order to connect.

Comment: I am not using azure service bus, I am using windows server service bus, hence I have to use the legacy version `qpid-amqp-1-0-client-jms` but then which version of that 0.32 or there any other version which is compatible with window server service bus, whose development has stopped since 2013

Comment: Nonetheless you still have two client jars in your project so who knows what you are really doing or ending up with.

Comment: @tim-bash can you please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769498/windows-service-bus-error-peer-did-not-create-remote-endpoint-for-link-target)